# Leaflet Map Not Rendering - Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am attempting to learn Leaflet in Javascript (I traditionally use R).  My goal is to create a simple map that I can experiment with.  However, I can't get a map to render.  My code is below:

```js
// initialize the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([42.35, -71.08], 13);

// load a tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://tiles.mapc.org/basemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>, Data by <a href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
  maxZoom: 17,
  minZoom: 9
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello...</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

</body>
```

I am apple to get it to run in Stack's editor but not when I create traditional files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Check the order of your includes: your map instantiation code relies on Leaflet, but is included after Leaflet.

Comment: I appreciate that.  However, nothing is working.  I've tested to see if the source to the javascript file is working in addition to the css connection and everything is fine.

I'll have to keep experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works for me - but I had to disable Privacy Badger because it was blocking `unpkg.com`.

I also removed the `<link>` and `<script>` items referring to non-HTTP served resources.

The actual Javascript is the same as in your question.

HTH

```js
// initialize the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([42.35, -71.08], 13);

// load a tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://tiles.mapc.org/basemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>, Data by <a href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
  maxZoom: 17,
  minZoom: 9
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello...</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</body>
```